# Need to filter through results from URL

Tags: ios, xcode, parsing, url, swift

This is using Apples Swift programming language. I have some code that gets information from http://camphalfblood.wikia.com/wiki/Camp_Half-Blood_Wiki

I want to grab the random quote of the moment but I am new to coding and would like some help. I have got so far but do not know how to continue. I have a text file that contains what the URLnodes puts to the console. I am using the TFHpple to get the html data. I am not sure the type of information coming in. The quote on the file is: (which says it multiple times. Don't know why)

"Annabeth took the dagger and studied it in awe. I know... she was seven years old at most. What was I thinking giving her a weapon? But she was a demigod. We have to defend ourselves. Hercules was only a baby when he strangled two snakes in his cradle. By the time I was nine, I'd fought for my life a dozen times. Annabeth could use a weapon."

My loadData function is called when the view loads.

```
func loadData () {
    let URLString = NSURL(string: "http://camphalfblood.wikia.com/wiki/Camp_Half-Blood_Wiki")
    let URLData = NSData(contentsOfURL: URLString!)
    let URLParser:TFHpple = TFHpple(HTMLData: URLData)
    let URLXpathQueryString:String = "//table[@class=\"cquote\"]"
    let URLnodes = URLParser.searchWithXPathQuery(URLXpathQueryString)

    println(URLnodes)
}
```

Link to file that contains what the URLnodes sends to the console - https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B-3F78LSPZtpamVhcC1VSnRJcWs&authuser=0

I have been on this for a while and cannot do this without help. To make it clear I want the quote from the website that I have been able to get with some other stuff. I need help to grab just the quote which changes when the webpage is reloaded.

All suggestions are welcomed. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are trying to parse the random quote string, you have a few options: one is to create a crawler yourself but another option is to use a simple third party free service like Kimono Labs (https://www.kimonolabs.com/) which turns websites into structured APIs.

Depending on the needs of your app and whether you have an interest in building a custom web crawler, I would suggest looking into Kimono Labs.

For example: here is an output that parses National Football League Scores: https://www.kimonolabs.com/api/46qt98nk?apikey=[YOURKIMINOLABSAPIKEY]

Once you have your quote returned in JSON format, it will be straightforward to get the random quote via NSJSONSerialization to a Dictionary.

*I have no affiliation with kimonolabs.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I will try doing this today and will let you know if I need any more help if that is ok. Thanks again.